# How to fix non-atomic use of get/check/put?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic, static-analysis

I have a JSONArray which I am iterating to populate my Map as shown below. My `ppJsonArray` will have data like this -

```
[693,694,695,696,697,698,699,700,701,702]
```

Below is my code which is having issues with thread safety as my static analysis tool complained -

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
ConcurrentMap<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> partitionsToNodeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>();
int hostNum = 2;

JSONArray ppJsonArray = j.getJSONArray("pp");
for (int i = 0; i < ppJsonArray.length(); i++) {
    m.put(Integer.parseInt(ppJsonArray.get(i).toString()), hostNum);
}
Map<Integer, Integer> tempMap = partitionsToNodeMap.get("PRIMARY");
if (tempMap != null) {
    tempMap.putAll(m);
} else {
    tempMap = m;
}
partitionsToNodeMap.put("PRIMARY", tempMap);
```

But when I am running static analysis tool, it is complaining as -

```
Non-atomic use of get/check/put on partitionsToNodeMap.put("PRIMARY", tempMap)
```

Which makes me think my above code is not thread safe? How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is not thread safe.

Does it need to be thread safe?  (i.e.,  Is partitionsToNodeMap used by more than one thread?  Could more than one thread run this routine? or could thread A thread update partitionsToNodeMap in some other routine while thread B runs this routine?)

If you answered "yes" to any of those questions, then you probably need to use some kind of synchronization.

---

partitionsToNodeMap is a ConcurrentHashMap.  That will prevent the map structure itself from becoming corrupt if it is updated by more than one thread at one time; but the data in the map presumably aren't just random strings and integers.  It probably *means* something to your program.  The fact that the map structure itself is protected from corruption will not prevent the higher-level meaning of the map contents from becoming corrupt.

---

> Can you provide an example how can I protect this?

Not a complete one, because thread-safety is a property of the whole program.  You can't do thread-safety function-by-function.

Being thread-safe is all about protecting *invariants*.  An invariant is an assertion about your data that must always be true.  For example, if you were modeling a game of Monopoly, one invariant would say that the total amount of money in the game must always be $15,140.

If some thread in the Monopoly game processes a payment by taking X dollars away from one player, and returning it to the bank, that's a two step process, and in-between the two steps the invariant is *broken*.  If the first thread were preempted in-between the two steps, and some other thread counted all of the money in the game, it would get the wrong total.

The main use-case for the Java `synchronized` keyword (or equivalently, for the java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock class) is to prevent other threads from seeing broken invariants.

Either way of locking is *voluntary*.  To make it work, you must wrap every block of code that can temporarily break an invariant in a protected block

```
synchronized(bank-lock) {
    deductNDollarsFrom(N, player);
    giveNDollarsTo(N, bank);
}
```

*AND* every block of code that *cares* about the invariant must also be wrapped in a protected block.

```
synchronized(bank-lock) {
    int totalDollars = countAllMoneyInGame(...);
    if (totalDollars != 15140) {
        throw new CheatingDetectedException(...);
    }
}
```

Java won't let the balance transfer and the audit happen at the same time because it never allows two threads to synchronize on the same object (bank-lock, in this case) at the same time.

You will have to figure out what your invariants are.  The static analyzer is telling you that the get()...put() sequence looks like a block of code that might *care* about an invariant.  You have to figure out whether it really does or not.  Is there something that some other thread could do in-between the get() and the put() that could cause things to go south?  If so then both blocks of code should synchronize on the same object so that they can not both be executed at the same time.

Comment: Yes it has to be thread safe. Yes those numbers means something to my program. Can you provide an example how can I protect this?

Answer (score 0):

Your static analysis tool is confused because what you're doing looks like a classic race condition.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> tempMap = partitionsToNodeMap.get("PRIMARY");  // GET
if (tempMap != null) {  // CHECK
    tempMap.putAll(m);
} else {
    tempMap = m;
}
partitionsToNodeMap.put("PRIMARY", tempMap);  // PUT
```

If another thread were to `partitionsToNodeMap.put("PRIMARY");` after you get assign `tempMap`, you would overwrite the other thread's work.  Among a myriad of other potential bad things.  It seems like you don't have multiple threads accessing it though, so it isn't an issue.  However, it would be more clearly expressed as:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> primaryMap = partitionsToNodeMap.get("PRIMARY");
if (primaryMap != null) {
    primaryMap.putAll(m);
} else {
    partitionsToNodeMap.put("PRIMARY", m);
}
```

If you want to make the static analysis tool happy, swap out your concurrent map for a regular map.  The code you've provided doesn't require a threadsafe data structure.